# Олимпиадное задание по комбинаторике

Tags: c, алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика, олимпиада

У меня вопрос на счет возможных вариантов размещения скобок разными способами. В чем суть: У меня дано N открытых и N закрытых скобок. Нужно посчитать количество разных вариантов закрытия скобок, при том, что возможно K разных стилей скобок(`()`, `[]`, `{}` т.д.)

**Например:**
N = 2, K = 2; — `([ ])`, `[()]`, т.д. - как результат мы получили такие варианты (всего их 8))

**Вопрос к вам**: Какая формула решения этой задачи или вообщем алгоритм?

Comment: *Любыми* способами или только *правильными*? Т.е. можно ли `)(`, `([)]` и тому подобные?

Comment: Скобки только вложенные или допускается `() []`?

Comment: Только правильным способом, на счет вложенных - нет, допускается и так как вы указали.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то исходим из того, что правильных скобочных расстановок из N пар скобок можно сделать в количестве чисел Каталана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если разновидностей скобок K, то для каждой расстановки мы их можем расставить [image: введите сюда описание изображения] способами.

Итого общее количество -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

способов *правильных расстановок*.

Для N=2, K=2:  2^2*(6-4)=4*2=8...

*"По-моему, так." (с) Пух*

Литература: Д.Кнут, *Искусство программирования*, т.4а, раздел 7.2.1.6.

Поскольку вопрос о генерации всех расстановок скобок не ставился, код не писал.